# How to run JS Karma tests from Gradle

Tags: javascript, gradle, karma-runner

I am trying to add a Gradle task to my project to run Karma tests. The tests have been run manually from command line so far. I found a Gradle JS plugin but it doesn't seem to have Karma integration. Any solution besides executing them from a command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "test-unit": "karma start test/unit/conf/karma.js"
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'node'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.4'
    }
}



// javascript unit testing
task testUnit(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run', 'test-unit']

}
//include js unit tests into project build lifecycle
test.dependsOn testUnit
```

Comment: Here's another way without the gradle-node-plugin dep: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23116656/573389