# Run Karma using Gradle?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gradle, jasmine, karma-runner

I have Jasmine unit tests that I would like to run and get Istanbul code coverage reports for. I can run a command line script to run Karma in Jenkins, but it would be nice to have everything execute using my build.gradle.

Is it possible to run Karma using Gradle? I've searched google, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by creating and running an executable task in the build.gradle file:

```
task karma(type:Exec) 
{
    commandLine 'karma', 'start', '--single-run true'
}
```

Comment: This forces gradle to just hang for me

Comment: 10 2015 16:45:12.474:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
08 10 2015 16:45:13.143:INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)]: Connected on socket admVYbrvxOj_y5olAAAA with id 43812512
> Building 0% > :karma

Answer (score 5):

Following up here for anyone searching this in 2016 or later:

There's now a [Gradle Karma Plugin](https://github.com/craigburke/karma-gradle) that is worth considering.