# Gradle exec task hangs when running javascript unit tests with Karma

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, karma-runner

I am trying to run my javascript unit tests from my build tool gradle. If I from my project source repository run karma the tests pass, but from that same location if I run the same commands using gradle the test hangs. I have to cntl + C out.

The browser that karma launches just hangs open. Upon further inspection I can see that my tests are passing, yet the browser doesn't exit.

```
karma start --single-run true
08 10 2015 16:38:07.607:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
08 10 2015 16:38:07.612:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Safari
08 10 2015 16:38:08.349:INFO [Safari 9.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)]: Connected on socket S0oEA_C63p3UJxq_AAAA with id 27120637
08 10 2015 16:38:08.388:INFO [Safari 9.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)]: Connected on socket Sm-S0etS3fGu-MB_AAAB with id 66671614
Safari 9.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.009 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS

gradle karma
:karma
08 10 2015 16:50:09.773:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
08 10 2015 16:50:09.779:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
08 10 2015 16:50:11.201:INFO [Firefox 41.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)]: Connected on socket 9AFBXsk5EfGKsFt_AAAA with id 32194330
08 10 2015 16:50:17.260:WARN [Firefox 41.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)]: Disconnected (1 times)
> Building 0% > :karma
```

**Gradle Task**

```
task karma(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'karma', 'start', '--single-run true'
}
```

**Karma Console**

```
SUCCESS  test all the core libraries debug.html:35:1
SUCCESS  should be three debug.html:35:1
Skipped 0 tests debug.html:25:29
```

I pulled this gradle task directly from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021646/run-karma-using-gradle/23116656#23116656) here

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

In my karma.conf.js file I had

```
singleRun: false
```

once I changed it to  true it worked

**FIX**

change this setting in your karma.conf.js file

```
singleRun: true
```